# HashMap.clone() returns shallow copy, but doesn't reflect the Value Change

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

Java doc says `HashMap.clone()` returns a shallow copy.

So I expect that if I change the value of some key in original `HashMap`, the cloned one will also see the change. Thus, I have this:

```
public class ShallowCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(2,"microsoft");
        map.put(3,"yahoo");
        map.put(1,"amazon");

        // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to
        // HashMap<Integer, String> Java(16777761)
        Map<Integer, String> mClone = 
            (HashMap<Integer, String>)map.clone();
        String previous = map.replace(3, "google");
        System.out.println(previous); // yahoo
        System.out.println(map.get(3)); // google
        System.out.println(mClone.get(3)); // yahoo, but why?
    }
}
```

In my code, I called `HashMap.replace()` and I see the value in `map` is changed from `"yahoo"` to `"google"`.
Strangely, the last line prints the previous value when looking for it in `mClone`.

But the fact is it prints `"yahoo"` not `"google"` as I expected.
Where does it get wrong, please kindly fix my understandings?

Plus: I also got a compiler warning as I commented in my `code(Java(16777761))`, how to fix it?

Comment: its a shallow copy in the sense that it doesn't deep clone the contents itself.

Comment: If you mutated the value objects, it'd be different.  Just replacing them won't affect the other map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

After the cloning operation the values are simply references to the same object.  So if you were to modify one reference in one map, the other would also be modified. But you didn't modify the object you replaced it.  At that point it became distinct from a reference perspective.

**Example**

The clone operation is working just as you presumed. But you are interpreting the results incorrectly. Consider the following class.

```
class FooClass {
    int a;
    public FooClass(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a + "";
    }
}
```

And now create a map and its clone.

```
HashMap<Integer, FooClass> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(10, new FooClass(25));
HashMap<Integer,FooClass> mClone = (HashMap<Integer,FooClass>)map.clone();
```

The values of each key are the same object reference. As shown by the following:

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(map.get(10)));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(mClone.get(10)));
```

prints

```
1523554304
1523554304
```

So if I modify one, it will modify the other.

The same was true for the String values of your maps.  But when you replaced `"yahoo"` with `"google"` you didn't modify the String you replaced it with a different Object.

If I were to do the same for FooClass, here is the result.

```
System.out.println("Modifying same object");
mClone.get(10).setA(99);
System.out.println(map.get(10));
System.out.println(mClone.get(10));
```

prints

```
Modifying same object
99
99
```

But if I were to replace the object with a new one.

```
System.out.println("Replacing the instance");
FooClass previous = mClone.replace(10, new FooClass(1000));
System.out.println("Previous = " + previous);
System.out.println("map: " + map.get(10));
System.out.println("mClone: " + mClone.get(10));
```

prints

```
Replacing the instance
Previous = 99
map: 99
mClone: 1000
```

And this latter operation is what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Method [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#clone()) creates a **new** *map* which gets populated with references to the *values* and *keys* contained in the source map, it's **not** a view of the initial map but an *independent collection*.

When you're calling `map.replace(3, "google")` a value mapped to the key `3` gets replaced with a new string, however the *cloned map* remains unaffected, it stills holds a reference to the same string `"yahoo"`.